# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' flutter

Tags: flutter

iam new to flutter and trying to fetch data from api for testing but i have some errors, here is the link that iam trying to fetch data from it and display it into FutureBuilder but i can't get to the information any one can help me !

here is my code:

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  Future<List<Post>> fetchData() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(apiUrl);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var obj = json.decode(res.body);
      List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
      for(int i=0;i>obj.length;i++){
        Post post = Post.fromJson(obj[i]);
        posts.add(post);
        print(post.name);
      }
      return posts;
    }

  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchData();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchData(),
          builder: (ctx,snapShot){
            if(snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(),
                      title: Text(""),
                      subtitle: Text(""),
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the link that i transform api json to [dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Comment: Error is within your Post.fromJson() method. Can you show its implementation ?

Comment: i > obj.length ? and still working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i=0;i>obj.length;i++){
  Post post = Post.fromJson(obj[i]);
  posts.add(post);
  print(post.name);
}
return posts;
```

To

```
var response = List<Post>.from(obj.map((i) => Post.fromJson(i)));
return response;
```

After, add `itemCount: snapShot.data.length` into your `ListView.builder`

Comment: yeah it worked but i can't call it in the FutureBuilder when i make snapShot.data[index]

Comment: try add itemCount: snapShot.data.length into your ListView.builder